# How to set base test environment in order to use with inherit classes?

Tags: inheritance, system-verilog, uvm

I have wrote axi4_stream test environment. It's work good, but now I need to test design with seq_item which inherit previous item. Theese item overrides convert2string and do_compare functions.

I thought to parameterized all the axi4_stream classes by seq_items, but in hour of trying to do this I concluded that it's just a pain, and I need to dig in different direction.

here prototypes of my classes
original:

```
class axi4_s_seq_item extends uvm_sequence_item;
class axi4_s_sequence extends uvm_sequence#(axi4_s_seq_item);
class axi4_s_sequencer extends uvm_sequencer#(axi4_s_seq_item);
class axi4_s_master extends uvm_driver#(axi4_s_seq_item);
class axi4_s_slave extends uvm_driver();
class axi4_s_monitor extends uvm_monitor;
class axi4_s_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;
class axi4_s_agent extends uvm_agent;
...
```

how I thought to change:

```
class new_axi4_s_seq_item extends axi4_s_seq_item;

class axi4_s_seq_item extends uvm_sequence_item;
class axi4_s_sequence#(type seq_item = axi4_s_seq_item) extends uvm_sequence#(seq_item);
class axi4_s_sequencer#(type seq_item = axi4_s_seq_item) extends uvm_sequencer#(seq_item);
class axi4_s_master#(type seq_item = axi4_s_seq_item) extends uvm_driver#(seq_item);
class axi4_s_slave extends uvm_driver();
class axi4_s_monitor#(type seq_item = axi4_s_seq_item) extends uvm_monitor;
class axi4_s_scoreboard#(type seq_item = axi4_s_seq_item) extends uvm_scoreboard;
class axi4_s_agent#(type seq_item = axi4_s_seq_item) extends uvm_agent;
...
```

I guess I can use defines to change class names, but still I think there is OOP solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the UVM factory to set your overrides; don't try do everything with parameter overrides. This [DVCon paper](https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/resources/overview/using-parameterized-classes-and-factories-the-yin-and-yang-of-object-oriented-verification-3a0d85f2-1456-4757-8b07-126895d23a60) is pre-UVM, but still relevant for UVM for explaining the differences between parameterization and inheritance.

Comment: You're right, thank you! But eventualy I found solution by this guide: https://cluelogic.com/2012/11/uvm-tutorial-for-candy-lovers-10-inside-candy-factory/
All I had to do was add a line:
`axi4_s_seq_item::type_id::set_type_override(abs_seq_item::get_type());`  
to test build phase.